# Estimating percent change on average

Tags: estimation, mean, percentage

Suppose I want to estimate the percent change of something over a fixed amount of time.  I have some values of before and after, so I can either choose to get the average of the "before" values and the average value of the "after" values and take the percent change, or I can calculate the percent changes and then take the average.  Which should I use?

Edit: Here is an example:

Suppose in one test I have a before value of 29.53 and an after value of 28.49.

For my second test I have a before value of 22.7 and an after value of 23.1.

Method 1:

The percent change in the first test is -3.52%, and the percent change in the second test is 1.76%.  The average of these is -0.88%.

Method 2:

The average of the before values is 26.115, and the average of the after values is 25.795.  The percent change is then ((25.795-26.115)/26.115)*100%=-1.225%.

So which would be a better estimate? -0.88% or -1.225%?

Comment: This can be a difficult problem, can you give some context? As an example,  see  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16984328

Answer (score 2):

If you want to report the *average change*, you calculate each person's change value as the ratio of post to pre values, and then you average all these changes together. If you want to report the *change in averages*, you average all post values and all pre values and take the ratio of these averages. Both methods are correct, depending on the question as you state it.